# Load advert on click

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, hyperlink

So, I have a HTML page with  links to video files on my server. What I need is, when someone clicks on the video links, a script should start loading up the advert from Google Adsense.

And after 10 seconds, it should be automatically redirected to the video file.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't do that as your Google Adsense account will be closes, as showing ads in pop-ups, or in new windows is against Adsense TOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure that goes against the crazy adsense TOS. Read them again before getting banned.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that illegal?

You need to change the link to the video with a simple text (in ) and add
the "onClick" attribute which will activate a JS function.

```
<div onClick="javascript:showAdvertAndRedirect('http://www.video.com/id/23233')">Click to see the video</div>
```

The js function will show the ad (by changing another div's innerHTML)
and will also run a timer of 10 seconds (actually a delay) , eventually will redirect
the visitor to the mentioned url.